# Camel in/out messages and correlation ID confusion

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, integration, messaging

I'm confused how Camel automatically forms messages and correlation identifiers, when using message queues.

For an example, I have two service with following routes

```
<route id="cxfToJMSRoute">

        <from uri="cxf:bean:endpoint" />
        <convertBodyTo type="String" />

        <log message="..." />
        <log message="In message: ${in.body}" />
        <log message="In JMSMessageID: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="In JMSCorrelationID: ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <log message="Out message: ${out.body}" />
        <log message="Out JMSMessageID: ${out.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="Out JMSCorrelationID: ${out.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <log message="Invoking service A by sending InOut message to api queue" />
        <to uri="activemq:queue:api?replyTo=result&amp;replyToType=Exclusive"
            pattern="InOut" />

        <log message="..." />
        <log message="Got message from Service A" />
        <log message="In message: ${in.body}" />
        <log message="In JMSMessageID: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="In JMSCorrelationID: ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <log message="Out message: ${out.body}" />
        <log message="Out JMSMessageID: ${out.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="Out JMSCorrelationID: ${out.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <!-- Correlation ID? -->
        <pollEnrich>
            <constant>activemq:queue:reply</constant>
        </pollEnrich>

        <log message="..." />
        <log message="Got message from Service B" />
        <log message="In message: ${in.body}" />
        <log message="In JMSMessageID: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="In JMSCorrelationID: ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <log message="Out message: ${out.body}" />
        <log message="Out JMSMessageID: ${out.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="Out JMSCorrelationID: ${out.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <transform>
            <simple>${in.body}</simple>
        </transform>

        <log message="After transform:" />
        <log message="In message: ${in.body}" />
        <log message="In JMSMessageID: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="In JMSCorrelationID: ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

        <log message="Out message: ${out.body}" />
        <log message="Out JMSMessageID: ${out.header.JMSMessageID}" />
        <log message="Out JMSCorrelationID: ${out.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />
        <log message="..." />
    </route>
```

--

```
<route id="apiToServiceARoute">
      <from uri="activemq:queue:api"/>

      <log message="..." />
      <log message="In message: ${in.body}" />
      <log message="In JMSMessageID: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}" />
      <log message="In JMSCorrelationID: ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

      <log message="Out message: ${out.body}" />
      <log message="Out JMSMessageID: ${out.header.JMSMessageID}" />
      <log message="Out JMSCorrelationID: ${out.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

      <log message="Mocking service B by sending InOnly message to reply queue" />
      <to uri="activemq:queue:reply?exchangePattern=InOnly" pattern="InOnly" />

      <transform>
        <simple>Delegated</simple>
      </transform>

      <log message="..." />
      <log message="After transform:" />
      <log message="In message: ${in.body}" />
      <log message="In JMSMessageID: ${in.header.JMSMessageID}" />
      <log message="In JMSCorrelationID: ${in.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />

      <log message="Out message: ${out.body}" />
      <log message="Out JMSMessageID: ${out.header.JMSMessageID}" />
      <log message="Out JMSCorrelationID: ${out.header.JMSCorrelationID}" />
      <log message="..." />
  </route>
```

Here are my observations according to log messages

1. `OUT` message is always empty. Does Camel always use `IN` by default, until `OUT` is created by some processor excliptly?
2. `JMSMessageID` and `JMSCorrelationID` doesn't seem to have any connection. Does Camel *only* use `JMSCorrelationID` for correlating messages?
3. Camel manages to retain the `JMSCorrelationID` when sending `InOnly` message to another queue (reply) where the request originates from. This is desirable, but how does it actually do it? What are the **specific rules** of retaining the `JMSCorrelationID`?

And here are the actual logs of both example routes

```
2017-12-03 12:16:06.197  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : ...
2017-12-03 12:16:06.197  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In message: testi2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.198  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.198  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.198  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out message:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.198  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.198  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.198  INFO 13780 --- [qtp335580595-36] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Invoking service A by sending InOut message to api queue
2017-12-03 12:16:06.569  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : ...
2017-12-03 12:16:06.570  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Got message from Service A
2017-12-03 12:16:06.570  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In message: Delegated
2017-12-03 12:16:06.582  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSMessageID: ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-54036-1512296151920-1:1:1:1:1
2017-12-03 12:16:06.582  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSCorrelationID: Camel-ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1512296077166-0-2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.582  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out message:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.582  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.583  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.596  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : ...
2017-12-03 12:16:06.596  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Got message from Service B
2017-12-03 12:16:06.596  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In message: testi2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.597  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSMessageID: ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-54036-1512296151920-3:1:1:1:1
2017-12-03 12:16:06.597  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSCorrelationID: Camel-ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1512296077166-0-2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.597  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out message:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.597  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.597  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : After transform:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In message: testi2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSMessageID: ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-54036-1512296151920-3:1:1:1:1
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : In JMSCorrelationID: Camel-ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1512296077166-0-2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out message:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : Out JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.598  INFO 13780 --- [Manager[result]] cxfToJMSRoute                            : ...
```

--

```
2017-12-03 12:16:06.528  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : ...
2017-12-03 12:16:06.531  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : In message: testi2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.534  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : In JMSMessageID: ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-54046-1512296166309-1:1:2:1:1
2017-12-03 12:16:06.534  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : In JMSCorrelationID: Camel-ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1512296077166-0-2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.534  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Out message:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.535  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Out JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.535  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Out JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.535  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Mocking service B by sending InOnly message to reply queue
2017-12-03 12:16:06.558  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : ...
2017-12-03 12:16:06.558  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : After transform:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.558  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : In message: Delegated
2017-12-03 12:16:06.558  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : In JMSMessageID: ID:DESKTOP-LI5P50P-54046-1512296166309-1:1:2:1:1
2017-12-03 12:16:06.559  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : In JMSCorrelationID: Camel-ID-DESKTOP-LI5P50P-1512296077166-0-2
2017-12-03 12:16:06.559  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Out message:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.559  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Out JMSMessageID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.559  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : Out JMSCorrelationID:
2017-12-03 12:16:06.559  INFO 16972 --- [msConsumer[api]] apiToServiceARoute                       : ...
```

Comment: Its almost always based on correlationId. It is the same in IBM MQ and RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. `OUT` message is always empty. Does Camel always use `IN` by default, until `OUT` is created by some processor explicitly?

Yes. Cloning of whole `org.apache.camel.Message` is really expensive. `OUT` is created on demand, during first call of `Exchange#getOut`

See [Apache Camel: Message exchange patterns and the Exchange object](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html)

---

> 2. `JMSMessageID` and `JMSCorrelationID` doesn't seem to have any connection. Does Camel only use `JMSCorrelationID` for correlating messages?

Not exactly. `camel-jms` (and `camel-activemq`, which is extending it) component copies header `JMSCorrelationID` to header `CamelCorrelationId`.

Correlation in `pollEnrich` is again working with `CamelCorrelationId` and `camel-jms` translates this header as message selector `JMSCorrelationID=CamelCorrelationId`.

So Yes, while communicating between `camel-jms` (and inherited components) endpoints and `exchangePattern=InOnly`, correlation will be done effectively on header `JMSCorrelationID`.

See [Apache Camel: Correlation Identifier](http://camel.apache.org/correlation-identifier.html)

---

> 3. Camel manages to retain the `JMSCorrelationID` when sending InOnly message to another queue (reply) where the request originates from. This is desirable, but how does it actually do it? What are the **specific rules** of retaining the `JMSCorrelationID`?

Camel does **no** transformation of `JMSCorrelationID` when using `exchangePattern=InOnly`.

On input route, Camel gets correlation id from input `javax.jms.Message` and saves it to `org.apache.camel.Message#headers.JMSCorrelationId`.

On output route Camel gets correlation id from `org.apache.camel.Message#headers.JMSCorrelationId` and sets it to `javax.jms.Message.setJMSCorrelationID()`.

*Note: I am not developer of Apache Camel. Every word I have written in this answer is based on user experience while using this framework. There could be minor discrepancies in answer.*